What does Mark Watney's plaque say?
We see Teddy giving a speech about Mark's noble sacrifice. He's standing in front of a plaque and a monument dedicated to Mark.

Is there a better shot of the grave marker that shows the whole thing?

NA[SA] something something [astr]onaut
Who has made something something Space Program
Believing something something [t]he risk of life


Not in my copy... it's static one-shot as you have it.

@Paulie_D - I was hoping for a set photo, maybe. It looks like a physical prop

the last line is likely "believing the conquest of space to be worth the risk of life" as an almost-quote of Gus Grissom

I assume the last word on the first line is 'astronaut'. Not that it helps work out the rest of it.

The middle line is likely to be something along the lines of ...(MAD)e the ultimate sacrifice for the Martia(N)..., where the bits in brackets are the parts you can see aready.

@bob1 - Who has mad [skillz which is why we put him on the dam] n space program

@Valorum It is a movie after all, so I wouldn't put it past the set makers to do something like that as an internal joke/easter egg

Believing in incorrect grammar and unlimited thickshakes, he risk of life.

Probably something like: "NASA's first space pirate potato farming astronaut"

2nd line is "Who has made us look really bad when we killed him with our space program"

@JK. there's another line, hidden by the guy standing there, that reads "addendum: he survived"
